# Best way to use this IF statement and && Logical expression

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, guid

```
require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

$errors = array(); 


if(empty($_POST['senFirstName']) && empty($_POST['senLastName']) 
&& empty($_POST['recFirstName']) && empty($_POST['recLastName']) 
&& empty($_POST['proName']) && empty($_POST['proWeight']) 
&& empty($_POST['traNo']) &&  empty($_POST['shipDate']) 
&& empty($_POST['deliDate'])) {

    $errors[] = 'Please make sure you type in all the information.';

}
else {
    $sfn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['senFirstName']));
    $sln = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['senLastName']));
    $rfn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['recFirstName']));
    $rln = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['recLastName']));
    $pn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['proName']));
    $pw = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['proWeight']));
    $traNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['traNo']));
    $shipDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['shipDate']));
    $deliDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['deliDate']));
    $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['status']));
    $shiptype = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['shiptype']));
    }   


if(empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.

$query = "SELECT traNo, CONCAT(recFirstName, ' ', recLastName) AS recieverName, proName, CONCAT(senFirstName, ' ', senLastName) AS senderName, status, shiptype FROM tracking, rel_tracking_reciever, reciever, product, sender
    WHERE traNo='$traNo' AND tracking.traId = rel_tracking_reciever.traId AND reciever.recId = rel_tracking_reciever.recId AND tracking.proId = product.proId AND tracking.senId = sender.senId";

    $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query); 
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num) { // tracking number was found

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


        echo '<div id="error">';
        echo "<p>This tracking number <b>{$row['traNo']}</b> has already been assigned to <b>{$row['senderName']}</b></p>\n";
        echo '</div>';
    }
    mysqli_free_result ($result); // Free up the resources.
    }
```

1) I want to validate input box with the multiple IF conditions using && Logical expression but instead, it submits empty forms into the database.
Note: I purposely left out the shipment and status input box because the options cannot be empty by default.

2) Is there a way i can generate the tracking number automatically without typing it manually. I have tried GUID but am not getting it.

Thanks..

Comment: I think you might mean || instead of &&... you're testing to see if __every__ $_POST value is empty, not if __any__ $_POST value is empty

Comment: Yes I want every $_POST checked and i supposed the && should do just that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set ids that you want to validate - there is no complain.

You can do this with:

```
$ids = array('senFirstName', 'senLastName', 'recFirstName', 'recLastName' /* ... and more */);
$valid = true;

foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
  if ( empty($_POST[$id]) ) {
    $valid = false;
  }
}

if ( $valid === true ) {
  // everything's ok
} else {
  $errors[] = 'Please make sure you type in all the information.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need ||, not && if you want to test, if one is empty.

Otherwise you would proove, if all of them are empty.

(Sorry for bad english)

```
if(empty($_POST['senFirstName']) || empty($_POST['senLastName'])  ...
```